# using BULK INSERT via Python

Tags: python, mysql, csv, sql-insert

I have problems splitting the values ​​of bulk-insert because the idea is to make 1 insert every 10 values ​​at a time and reading the entire contents of CSV file

The code already inserts in a single line reading the entire CSV file but I am unable to perform the division of VALUES in the case in the future perform an insert of 10 thousand values ​​at a time.

```py
def bulk_insert(table_name, **kwargs):

    mysqlConnection = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id='id_db')
    a = mysqlConnection.get_conn()
    c = a.cursor()

    with open('/pasta/arquivo.csv') as f: 
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')

        sql ="""INSERT INTO user (id,user_name) VALUES""" 

            for row in reader:           
                sql +="(" + row[0] + " , '" + row[1] + "'),"
            c.execute(sql[:-1])  

    a.commit()
```

Comment: I would suggest just using MySQL's `LOAD DATA` bulk insert tool.  No need in re-inventing the wheel and trying to manually do this from a Python script.

Comment: The script is part of an ETL that is doing SQL from one database, exporting to CSV and then inserting it into another database. If I do it for LOAD DATA, I am not able to split the number of inserts in sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ought to work.  The `batch_csv` function is a generator that yields a list of rows of size `size` on each iteration.

The bulk_insert function is amended to use parameter substitution and the cursor's `executemany` method.  Parameter substitution is safer than manually constructing SQL.

`cursor.executemany` may batch SQL inserts as in the original function, though this is implementation-dependent and should be tested.

```
def batch_csv(size=10):
    with open('/pasta/arquivo.csv') as f: 
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        batch = []
        for row in reader:
            batch.append(row)
            if len(row) == size:
                yield batch
                del batch[:]
        yield batch


def bulk_insert(table_name, **kwargs):

    mysqlConnection = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id='id_db')
    a = mysqlConnection.get_conn()
    c = a.cursor()
    sql ="""INSERT INTO user (id,user_name) VALUES (%s, %s)""" 
    batcher = batch_csv()
    for batch in batcher:
        c.executemany(sql, [row[0:2] for row in batch])  

    a.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the test I performed the insertion was correct but I was only in doubt it was in a single line or several because you put a force in "executemany"  To further explain my doubt, the INSERT command should work like this ... `INSERT INTO user (id,username) VALUES (1,'name'),(2,'name) INSERT INTO user (id,username) VALUES (3,'name'),(4,'name)` ... It's not like that ... `INSERT INTO user (id,username) VALUES (1,'name'),(2,'name),(3,'name'),(4,'name')...` I think I should mess with a.commit () to do INSERT in batches.